# PowerShell error while running sync-unicorn in gulp while running VS task runner

Tags: gulp

I am trying to run gulp to publish changes in my localhost but while running 'sync-unicorn'. I am getting this error

Powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I checked PowerShell path is defined in the environment variable path.

Can anyone suggest me what can be the error.

Any help would be appreciable.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a Sitecore as much as a windows issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29778121/powershell-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-progr or https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4b4e1006-5c9f-4360-ac82-ffa880e8b75e/windows-10-powershell-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command-operable-program-or?forum=win10itprogeneral

Comment: How and where are you running the `gulp` command? In a generic `cmd`? In a Visual Studio `cmd` instance? A PowerShell prompt? Are you running elevated?

Comment: @nsturdivant I am running the commands in Visual studio task runner, yes I was running as elevated user.

Comment: hi @chris auer  I have already followd the first link yiu provided, it didn't help. will check the second link once i will get time. Thankyou

Comment: Try to `cd` to the relevant directory within an elevated PowerShell prompt and then run the `gulp` command.

Comment: @nsturdivant ok will try